# create new sheet in excel using existing macro

Tags: excel, vba

I have an Excel sheet having 600 000 records and when I apply the macro, records get reduced to 15k. How within the macro in can put all these 15k records in a new excel sheet?

The macro:

```
Sub DeleteRecord()
 ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 2
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 7
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 9
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 11
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 16
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 20
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 22
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 23
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 24
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 25
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 27
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 29
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 30
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 31
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 32
    Dim MySheet As String
MySheet = ActiveSheet.Name


    ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=33, Criteria1:= _
    ">=-.09", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=.01"
      Dim cnt As Long
    cnt = Worksheets(MySheet).Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row

   ActiveSheet.Range("A2", ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).Select
     If cnt > 3 Then
   Selection.EntireRow.Delete
End If
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 4
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 5
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 6
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 11
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 13
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 16
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 20
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 23
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 28
    ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn = 30
   ActiveSheet.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.AutoFilter Field:=33
  ' Range("Claims[[#Headers],[Change in Calculated Contribution]]").Select
  Cells(1, 33).Select
    Selection.AutoFilter
End Sub
```

Comment: Firstly, it would be good to explain in a few words what you intend to accomplish. Then, `ActiveWindow.ScrollColumn` is useless in your code, I would say. Then, do you like to firstly filter the `CurrentRegion` using some criteria and then delete the filtered area, if more then 3 rows are visible. Correct? Then you want filtering again the remained area on column 33 and the resulted filtered cells to be moved in a new worksheet. Is that understanding of your need correct?

Comment: yes.Sorry I am new I don't have much idea on this.I want after filter record.Remaining record.Create new sheet and paste all data in new sheet.If possible then you can optimise this code.your efforts are highly appreciated

Comment: One more thing: Your last filtering does nothing, without criteria. What would you like to do, in fact? To sort the range?

Comment: in last criteria I am removing filter.I am applying filter in one column name is change in calculated contribution

Comment: In this macro .We have applied the filter on Column < Change in calculated contribution > and after applying this filter ,The records which are coming in excel .I am deleting .     Once the data is deleted , I have to remove the filter condition and i am left with 15k records . I need to put these 15k left records in a new excel..Please let me know if excel sheet is required .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, test the next code. It also sort your resulted range after filtering. If  not needed, you can comment that code part. I use an array  to copy the content without using much resources (in case of a big range). If you also  need to copy the range format, you/we can use Copy - Paste:

```
Sub testFilterCopyNewSheet()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, cnt As Long, newSh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    If sh.AutoFilterMode Then sh.Cells.AutoFilter
    Set rng = sh.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
    rng.AutoFilter field:=33, Criteria1:= _
                    ">=-.09", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=.01"

        cnt = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row:
        If cnt > 3 Then
            sh.Range("A2", ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
   If sh.AutoFilterMode Then sh.Cells.AutoFilter
   Set rng = sh.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
    rng.Sort key1:=sh.Cells(1, 33), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    Set newSh = Worksheets.aDD(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.count))
     Dim arrSh As Variant
     arrSh = sh.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.value
     newSh.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrSh, 1), UBound(arrSh, 2)).value = arrSh
End Sub
```

Please, confirm that it does what you need. Tested on some tenth of rows.

Edited: Updated version, able to work on a huge range having a `listObject` (the filter is eliminated in a different way)...

Please test the next code:

```
Sub testFilterCopyNewSheet()
   Dim sh As Worksheet, rng As Range, cnt As Long, newSh As Worksheet
    Set sh = ActiveSheet
    sh.ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter
    Set rng = sh.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion
    rng.Sort key1:=sh.Cells(1, 33), order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes
    rng.AutoFilter field:=33, Criteria1:= _
                    ">=-0.09", Operator:=xlAnd, Criteria2:="<=0.01"

        cnt = sh.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row:

        If cnt > 3 Then
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
            Application.ScreenUpdating = False
            sh.Range("A2", ActiveCell.SpecialCells(xlLastCell)).EntireRow.Delete
        End If
            Application.EnableEvents = True
            Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
            Application.ScreenUpdating = True

   sh.ListObjects(1).Range.AutoFilter
   Set rng = sh.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion

    Set newSh = Worksheets.aDD(After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.count))
     Dim arrSh As Variant
     arrSh = sh.Range("A1").CurrentRegion.value
     With newSh.Range("A1").Resize(UBound(arrSh, 1), UBound(arrSh, 2))
        .value = arrSh
        .EntireColumn.AutoFit
    End With
End Sub
```

If you need the data in the new sheet to have the initial order (sorting), it also can be done. I can insert another column after the last existing, increment there a variable starting from 1 to the last row and finally resort the resulted range filtering on this column and then delete it.

If you need to play with the code, in order to see what filtering criteria are the best, the newly created sheet can be named (let us say: 'Result') and the code will previously search for it. If it exists it clears its content, if not, it creates a new one...

Comment: thanks man for your help.Please allow me 15 mint I will check and update you onece again thanks

Comment: Sorry this code is not working for me .its deleting all the data and creating a new excel with just headers in it

Comment: @Aditya Kaistha: Try run the code line by line, from VBE pressing F8 for each line and see what happens. Make the VBE window smaller in order to see what happens in Excel sheet. Firstly, put a break on the line `cnt = ActiveSheet.Cells.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeLastCell).Row:` and see the filtered area. To put such a break, select the line in discussion and press F9 in VBE (Visual Basic Editor). Are you sure that not all values in columns 33 are included in your 'criteria`? The code runs well, keeping only values outside your criteria. I tested the code before posting it.

Comment: can you give your email id I will provide you excel sheet..?

Comment: @Aditya Kaistha: You can find  my personal email in my profile...

Comment: thanks I send you mail attachment 55 MB.Let me know any clarification required

Comment: @Aditya Kaistha: I will look at it when I will find some time...

Comment: Ok Thanks.But it would very helpful if it would resolve with in hour because after one hour I have  to give demo after one hour mean while I am also look into this

Comment: @Aditya Kaistha: OK. I will look at it in less than an hour...

Comment: @Aditya Kaistha: Before I will open your file, I would like you to confirm that applying the filter like you have it, there are some hidden rows...

Comment: Sorry I don't much idea about this.its working fine.My requirement is after removing filter almost 12 k record left.Now I want to create new sheet and paste data in new sheet.

Comment: @Aditya Kaistha: It looks that for such a huge amount of rows to be deleted Excel is not able to do that only for the filtered rows if discontinuous  and it deletes everything... I will try to firstly sort the range in order to obtain the continuous range to be deleted. Of course, if you have more time to wait...

Comment: @Aditya Kaistha:  Yes, it works in this way... Let me do some more tests and I will post the updated code in less then 5 minutes...

Comment: @Aditya Kaistha: Updated the code. Please, test it and let me know if it works in your case, too.

Comment: @Aditya Kaistha:  Do not forget to refresh the page, in ofer to see the  new version!

Comment: I am still not able to execute

Comment: @Aditya Kaistha: What do you mean by not being able to execute? You just have to run the code being sure that active sheet is the one to be processed... Would you like me to transform your file in a .xlsm type, embed the code and send it back to you? It will take between 20 to 30 seconds in order to finish (according to your computer resources)... Are you sure you use the updated code? Did you refresh the page?

Comment: yes I think its working just allow me for few time.I will update you

Comment: @Aditya Kaistha: I, anyhow, sent you the .xlsm file, having a button to process the sheet as (I understood) you need.

Comment: Hi I am again facing same issue substring out of range.your macro is not working.can you please look into this. @FaneDuru

Answer (score 0):

```
'create new sheet
    Sheets("ScheduleTemplate").Copy After:=Worksheets(Worksheets.Count)
    Sheets("ScheduleTemplate (2)").Visible = True
    Sheets("ScheduleTemplate (2)").Select
    Sheets("ScheduleTemplate (2)").Name = NewName
```